# Python requests form-data method

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to automate retrieval of data from [this site](https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/jsp/KMCBirthRecordSearch.jsp).

My code goes:

```
import requests
a_session = requests.Session()
a_session.get('https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/jsp/KMCBirthRecordSearch.jsp')
session_cookies = a_session.cookies
cookie = session_cookies.get_dict()
ablu = {
    'FatherName': 'Cha',
    'dateofBirth': '19/08/2004',
    'MotherName': 'Cha',
}
referer = 'https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/jsp/KMCBirthRecordSearch.jsp'
url = 'https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/KMCBirthRegistrationAction.do?var=getVal'
r = requests.post(url, cookies=cookie, headers={"referer": referer}, data=ablu)
print(r.text)
```

The command line outputs `{failure:true,ERRORKEY:{"ERRORMESSAGE":"Please Contact your system administrator"}}`

I wonder what I am doing wrong. This is the first time I am trying to automate sending form-data.

### Update 1:

```
import requests
a_session = requests.Session()
a_session.get('https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/jsp/KMCBirthRecordSearch.jsp')
session_cookies = a_session.cookies
cookie = session_cookies.get_dict()
ablu = {
    'FatherName': 'Cha',
    'dateofBirth': '19/08/2004',
    'MotherName': 'Cha',
}
referer = 'https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/jsp/KMCBirthRecordSearch.jsp'
url = 'https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/KMCBirthRegistrationAction.do?var=getVal'
r = a_session.post(url, cookies=cookie, headers={"Referer": referer, "Accept": '*/*',
    "Accept-Encoding": 'gzip, deflate, br',
    "Accept-Language": 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8',
    "Connection": 'keep-alive',
    "Content-Length": '56',
    "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    "DNT": '1',
    "Host": 'www.kmcgov.in',
    "Origin": 'https://www.kmcgov.in',
    "sec-ch-ua": '"Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": '?0',
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"',
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": 'empty',
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": 'cors',
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": 'same-origin',
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36',
    "X-Requested-With": 'XMLHttpRequest'}, data=ablu)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Don't hard-code a session ID from another browser.  Session IDs expire.  Instead, visit the site once in your code and save the session cookie you get back.

Comment: @TimRoberts Did that, thanks. No change in output. I will be so glad if you can take a look!

Comment: Don't know.  I even added a `User-Agent` to the headers and it still fails.  They may have some browser-detection stuff going on to prevent automated reads.

Comment: You are not taking advantage of the session you initialize in your code. Instead of `requests.post` you should be using `a_session.post`. I would also advise you to spoof your user agent otherwise it's obvious you are a bot. Check in your browser what headers and cookies are being sent, and make sure you produce comparable results.

Comment: Replicated browser POST header (see code in Update 1) but to no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example.

First of all, note that we are using a **session**, so the cookies are automatically collected for you. There is no need to handle them manually.

Also, we can send *additional headers* when making a request on a case by case basis, but the session headers are included too and merged with your request. Please see here: [Python requests - Advanced Usage](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/).

In this case it's not even necessary to visit the page by issuing a get request first. You can send your POST request right away, it will work and it will return JSON-like data.

I think the crucial bit here was the parameter `dateOfBirth`. **Capitalization** is not the same in your original code. That must have been the reason why your requests failed on the server-side.

Also note that some headers like:

- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Content-Length: 56

will be populated automatically by the requests module as necessary.

```
import requests

a_session = requests.Session()
a_session.headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
}
# r = a_session.get('https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/jsp/KMCBirthRecordSearch.jsp')
# print(r.status_code)

ablu = {
    'FatherName': 'CHA',
    'dateOfBirth': '19/08/2004',
    'MotherName': 'CHA'
}

# additional headers
headers = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Origin": "https://www.kmcgov.in",
    "Referer": 'https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/jsp/KMCBirthRecordSearch.jsp',
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin"
}
url = 'https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/KMCBirthRegistrationAction.do?var=getVal'
r = a_session.post(url, headers=headers, data=ablu)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, it works for me, maybe you're unnecessarily providing `cookies` to `requests.post(...)`:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.kmcgov.in/KMCPortal/KMCBirthRegistrationAction.do?var=getVal'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin"
}

payload = {
    'FatherName': 'CHA',
    'dateOfBirth': '19/08/2004',
    'MotherName': 'CHA'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

EDIT:

Ok, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.